# Check the proof of $||x||^2$ is not a norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Show if $f$ is a norm:
For $\mathbb{R}^n$, Define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by $ f(x) = \|x\|^2$ =$\sum_{n} x_n^2 $

I tried to solve if $f$ satisfies the three properties of a norm: 1) zero vector 2)positive homogeneity 3)Triangle Inequality.

It satisfies the 1st property obviously.

For the 2nd property, I got $f(ax)= ||ax||^2=ax \cdot ax=a^2||x||^2 \neq |a|||x||^2$, so $f$ does not satisfy the 2nd property.

For the 3rd property, I got $f(x+y)=||x+y||^2=(x+y)\cdot (x+y)=||x||^2+2x\cdot y+||y||^2$. In order to satisfy the triangle inequality, it has to be that $||x||^2+2x\cdot y+||y||^2 \le ||x||^2+||y||^2$, i.e, $x \cdot y \le 0$, but there's no guarantee that $x \cdot y \le 0$, therefore the triangule inequality is not satisfied.

Since $f$ does not satisfy the second and third property, it is not a norm in $\Bbb R^n$.

Is the above proof correct? If it's not right, could someone provide a proof of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. You didn't have to do the third case: after 2) you already know that it is not a norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show that the $2^{nd}$ property does not hold. This is sufficient to disprove that $\lVert x\rVert^2$ is a norm. A norm must satisfy *all* of the properties.

In short: your proof is correct- but save yourself time and don't include anything besides your discussion of the second property.